# How to get Y-axis from Hue SQL queries for charts

Tags: mysql, sql, hue

I'm running MYSQL queries in Hue and need to graph the output.  However, I've been unable to locate information on how to populate the drop-down box for the Y-axis.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've used one example that used a count(*) to populate the Y-axis; is there a list somewhere of the different ways to create a Y-axis?  This method hasn't worked for my table.

The query below fails to provide any Y-axis options:

```
select 'country','year','predicted_sales'
from predictions
where prod_id='210'
order by 'year' asc;
```

The query below only returns a single column of output that is 100% of results:

```
select 'country','year',count(*) as pred
from predictions
group by 'country'
order by 'year' asc;
```

The tutorial I'm working from uses the code below; it returns multiple columns:

```
SELECT `start station`,
   `end station`,
   count(*) AS trips
FROM `itm_db`.`201402_trip_data`
GROUP BY `start station`,
     `end station`
ORDER BY trips DESC;
```

I'm not sure why mine don't work.  Not looking for someone to do the work for me; just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: you should show some data, and what you want to see or what your data represent

Comment: I added some blocks of code.  Thanks.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and then, we can see what you actually want

Comment: I found it.  My problem was that all of my values were stored as strings.  Once I cast my numerical strings as bigint, Hue let me plot the numbers on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  All of my variables in my tables were stored as character strings, which cannot be aggregated and used on the y-axis.  Once I cast my string variables as bigint I was able to plot the results on the y-axes of my charts and conduct a usable analysis.

Sometimes its the simplest things that throw you off!